# Getting name of PMML InputField in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a toy `DecisionTreeRegressor` model that as been exported to PMML using `sklearn2pmml`. I'm now trying to evaluate the model in Scala. I'd like to use the `getName` method of the `InputField` object to print names of all input variables. I have been able to develop the following (non-running code).

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.ArrayList

import org.dmg.pmml.PMML
import org.jpmml.evaluator.Evaluator
import org.jpmml.evaluator.InputField
import org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluatorFactory
import org.jpmml.model.ImportFilter
import org.jpmml.model.JAXBUtil
import org.xml.sax.InputSource

object PMMLTest extends App {
  def readPMML(filename: String): PMML = {
    val file = new File(filename)
    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
    try {
      val inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream)
      val source = ImportFilter.apply(inputSource)
      JAXBUtil.unmarshalPMML(source)
    } finally {
      inputStream.close()
    }
  }


  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val filename = "/path/to/decision_tree.pmml"
    val pMMLObject = readPMML(filename)
    val evaluator = ModelEvaluatorFactory.newInstance().newModelEvaluator(pMMLObject)
    val fields = evaluator.getInputFields.toArray.toList

    // Print string representation of all objects.
    /*
    Prints
      InputField{name=x6, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x13, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x8, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x1, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x10, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x3, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x11, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x12, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x7, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x9, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x2, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x5, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
      InputField{name=x4, dataType=FLOAT, opType=CONTINUOUS}
    */
    fields.foreach {println}

    // Print _name_ of all InputFields (should print x1, x2, ...)
    // Errors 
    for (f: InputField <- fields) {
      println(f.getName)
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile and run the above code, I get:

```
[error] /main/scala/PMMLTest.scala:32:24: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.jpmml.evaluator.InputField => Unit
[error]  required: Object => ?
[error]     for (f: InputField <- fields) {
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Feb 7, 2018 4:37:09 PM
```

You can probably tell from the above that I'm fairly new to Scala and PMML. My question is: How can I access the methods of the `InputField` object? I have already reviewed [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047109/get-actual-field-name-from-jpmml-models-inputfield) question, but I do see the variable names in my `.pmml` file.

I suspect this is probably a type inference issue, but dont know how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `fields` (defined above) is a `java.util.List` which needs to be converted into Scala List. The solution was the following:

Import `JavaConverters`

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

and convert the java `List` to Scala before looping

```
val fields = evaluator.getActiveFields.asScala

for (f: InputField <- fields) {
  println(f.getName)
}
```